# Appodeal ad implementation: onBannerFailedToLoad called for bannerAd on Android app

Tags: android

First time I've used an app key using my app's package name for ad visibility. But the ad didn't show up. Then I've used another app key using another package to my previous app and could see the ad. But when I used my previous app key (which is created using by my app's package name) then `onBannerFailedToLoad` is called.

I have received a mail from appodeal that they found my request but the ad is not showing because of the conflicting app key. How I can I solve this now?

Thanks in advance.